# Why should I use Arrow Functions here instead of a Class or Object Constructors?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small project, mainly to help teach myself JavaScript, and I have a question about a suggestion someone had.

My goal is to have a list of races and rpg classes that when I create a new character object I can assign it a race and an rpg class that it will gain the attributes of.

Here's my method and my reasoning behind it. I'm using a class to define the objects (I'm pretty sure is what I'm doing) that way I can create functions for those classes/objects to do things. Like on the Player class I can then create functions that manage the Player's inventory. and when I instantiate a new player I can assign them a race object and an rpg class object.

```
class Orc {
  constructor() {
    this.mortal = true
  }
}

class Player {
  constructor(race, name, level){
    var inventory = {};
    this.race = race;
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    this.inventory = inventory;
    this.currentCapacity = 0;
    this.maxCapacity = 50;
  }
}

const orc = new Player(new Orc(), 'Baz', 1 )
console.log(orc.race)
```

And here's the method I was suggested to use:

```
const raceTemplates = {
  human: { mortal: true }, 
  elf: { mortal: true }
}

const playerMaker = template => (race, name, level) => {
  return {
    name,
    level,
    race,
    inventory: {},
    currentCapacity: 0,
    maxCapacity: 50,
    ...template[race]
  }
}  

const player = playerMaker(raceTemplates)('elf', 'sammy', 2)
console.log(player)
```

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I've seen the Arrow Functions before however I'm pretty much entirely self taught so the theory of why some things are better than others is where I fall short on. I think I understand what Arrow Functions are but as I've said I'm new to JavaScript and self taught (have PluralSight course offerings through work that I've used) so I'm not too familiar with them.

Any help is appreciated and if this isn't a good question or it's already been answered I apologize. Thank you!

Comment: What is better here is mainly opinionated, and it depends how you might extend or add to your classes. There is a possible problem with the second approach, I could do something like `playerMaker(raceTemplates)('foo', 'sammy', 2)` even though there is no such `"foo"` race.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek That's a good point, in that case would it then almost be better to use my method?

Answer (score 2):

Of course this is opinionated, but to me a "classic" formulation of:

```
function playerMaker(template,race,name,level){
...
}
```

Would be clearer for someone reading it. The arrow syntax is just syntax sugar to not write "function". But here, creating a nested function that is returned from the master function to be invoked later seems both unintuitive and inefficient to me, in lack of any example where it would be useful as written.

Comment: I appreciate your response. In your suggestion, what is template referring to? Also now that I look at the suggestion that I shared in my question, I notice that it seems like it would be difficult to scale to allow the input of a rpg-class upon player creation. With your suggestion would that be possible?

Comment: I only replied to the concrete part of your question about the fat arrow syntax. Whether or how you should use classes is a broader question and you should provide much more detail in your question: what it is you're trying to achieve; how you plan to develop and manage development of said app; what, and how, your app needs to integrate with. It's a question of design, not syntax. In terms of language /syntax, both approaches are equivalent as long as you get the same result. So do update your question with all relevant details.

Comment: Ah I apologize for that. Wasn't sure what all information might be needed and I realize that I wasn't asking the right question. For now though I've gotten some good information and I need to go back and research some topics before I continue. I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Well just think of it this way: what if you were to persist (save the generated characters) from one day to the other. But between these days you will decide that for orc the maxCapacity is 100. Now you have a problem, as the value is already instantiated and persisted. So you might actually want a getCapacity() function that can be changed with the source without affecting the persisted data. Then the races: do they need any inheritance? Will there ever be a "Gray orc" that is like an orc but different? Etc. You need to take more into account for design than just coding style.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons not to use [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) in Javascript:

1. The concept of “Class” doesn’t exist in JavaScript.

   - > JavaScript classes, introduced in ECMAScript 2015, are primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax does not introduce a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript.
2. Concept of classes makes things brittle. Prototypes are better and very flexible (IMO, although I still will use them from time to time).
3. It guides people away from goodness and power of functional programming.

   - In JS functions are first-class citizens. Functional programming is all about using functions to their fullest extent. There is a notion called: “Favor Composition over Inheritance” and here we are going in the opposite direction because “Class” notation favors “Inheritance over Composition”.

Comment: Ah thank you for pointing these things out. I guess I started using "Classes" as a cushion since I was familiar with them. It will probably benefit me a ton to read more of the theory and reasoning behind JavaScript and good programming practices. I'll also have to look more into "Prototypes" as I've seen a lot of references towards them but am still unsure of how to use them. Thank you for your response!

Comment: While it doesn't necessarily contradict the above answer, I would add that just as well as there are reasons not to use classes, there are reasons to use them, too. They were a necessary addition to allow all the abstraction around class-based programming: strict inheritance, contract programming, reflexion. If you want your code to be extensible by people with very little knowledge of it, and their extensions integrated back in a larger order of things, then using classes is not such a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I agree with both of you, they definitely have their place. Also, they are so much easier to conceptualize that prototypal inheritance, no one would blame you for using classes as an alternative as you can still get the job done with them :)

Comment: Whether you should use functional programming or OOP is purely on the task you are working on. For example, you *can* make a game using a purely functional programming language like Haskel. But it's much more complex and difficult to do so because your putting a round peg in a square hole.

Comment: @mdkincaid, in regards to using arrow functions vs regular functions, that part is syntactic sugar (just btw, I neglected to gloss over that part on my answer)

Comment: Just to clarify some notions... Both styles are OOP, one is class based, one is not; and JS is not a functional language. Functional programming uses no state or mutable data. JS closures are not lambda functions in terms of functional programming, although they are sometimes referred to as such and just having functional parameters does not a language functional make.